# MSTest, EF6 and Simple Injector - Cannot insert duplicate key row in object in Integration Test

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, simple-injector

In an app ASPNET WebApi we are using SimpleInjector as IOC with EF6 Code First and the problem is that doing an update of an object, EF is not realizing that is the same and tries to create it again.

This runs OK when running it from the browser, but when we run it from the integration test is necessary to define a hybrid context as the LifeStyle we use in the IoC is by request and the test is Scope.

This is how we define the hybrid context.

```
Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
      () => Container.GetCurrentExecutionContextScope() != null,
      new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle(),
      new WebApiRequestLifestyle());

IocConfig.RegisterIoc(new HttpConfiguration(), Container);
```

Then we have to run the test defined in [AssemblyInitialize] that is responsible for creating the initial test data in the database.

For each individual test

```
[TestMethod, TestCategory("Nightly")][Ignore]
public void SearchLogsOrdersCorrectlyTest()
{
    using (GlobalInit.Container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
    {
        var subscriptionService = GlobalInit.Container.GetInstance<ISubscriptionService>();
        var subscriptionBaseModel = new SubscriptionBaseModel
            {
              AuditInformation = new AuditModel
               {
                 UserName = "User Name",
                 UserEmail = "username@domain.com",
                 UserHostname = "manage.domain.com",
                 UserIpAddress = "11.11.11.11"
               },
                 Company = new Company { Id = 1 },
                 Customers = new List<Customer> 
                   {
                     new Customer 
                       { 
                         Email = "email@dom.com", 
                         FullName = "Full Name" 
                       }
                   },
                 SubscriptionData = new SubscriptionPlanUpdateModel
                   {
                     AvailableLicenses = 1,
                     ContractId = "1111",
                     Url = "http://google.com ",
                     SubscriptionComments = ".",
                     ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1)
                   }
             };

        var subscriptionCreationModel = mappingEngine.Map<SubscriptionCreationModel>(subscriptionBaseModel);
        subscriptionCreationModel.Validate();
        Assert.IsTrue(subscriptionCreationModel.IsModelValid);

        var newSubscription = SubscriptionFactory.GetSubscription(subscriptionCreationModel);

        var savedSubscription = newSubscription.Save();
        Assert.IsNotNull(savedSubscription);
    }
}
```

Basically what the test does is take a model with basic data, adds data from the database and then saves it. The problem is it tries to insert the objects into the database as new ones instead of updating them. This seems to be because it understand they are from different contexts.

If we don't use the `GlobalInit.Container.BeginExecutionContextScope()` then we get an Exception that the Scope is different and can't inittiate a WebRequestScope outside a web context.

The peculiarity here is that all this is done within the:

```
using (GlobalInit.Container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
```

So if you have any idea that we are losing here, it will be well be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure this is line OK  :  Company = new Company { Id = 1 } ? , this create new company with id 1 all times

Comment: Yes this is fine, because when I call to SubscriptionFactory.GetSubscription() I use the company Id to retrieve the company from the DB. And this is exactly the problem, because when I try to save the model I got an exception that says that the Company alreary exists

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to define a hybrid lifestyle at all. It's just a matter of giving each application its own specific lifestyle.

```
// In the unit tests:
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle();
IocConfig.RegisterIoc(new HttpConfiguration(), container);


// In web api:
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestScope();
IocConfig.RegisterIoc(new HttpConfiguration(), container);
```

If you can, prevent polluting each test with handling the scopes. What you should do instead is move the starting and stopping of the scope to a base class into the constructor and `Dispose` method. This way it will run before and after each test. Example:

```
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase : IDisposable
{
    private Scope scope;
    public IntegrationTestBase() {
        this.scope = Container.BeginExecutionContextScope();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        this.scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This btw, would be a great place to add transaction handling as well:

```
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase : IDisposable
{
    private Scope scope;
    private TransactionScope transactionScope;
    public IntegrationTestBase() {
        this.scope = Container.BeginExecutionContextScope();
        this.transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        this.transactionScope.Dispose();
        this.scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This ensures that each test runs in isolation, and since we don't call `Complete` the transaction is rolled back at the end of each test. The only thing you have to do is inherit your test class from this base class.

As for your problem about why there are multiple scopes: I have no idea; you didn't provide enough information to see this. You probably create a second scope during the execution of that test.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's a good point that you mentioned but it didn't work. I got the same error when save the model.